# Toilet keeps blocking / bubbling and sink drains into toilet

Tags: toilet

We have recently had our bathroom refitted but the toilet keeps getting blocked up. When it happens the sink doesn't drain well or drains into the toilet.it is a combined toliet/ sink unit.

When it first happened the fitters removed the unit and cleared it and for a several weeks or so it was ok. However it has blocked again with the same issue. We've managed to clear it so that the toliet flushes and clears ok but can see that the sink drains into the toilet bowl.

What would be the cause of this happening yet again in such a short space of time.

Prior to the refit we didn't have these issues. Is it just coincidence or could there be a problem with the actual fitting of the pipestone the sink and toilet?

Thanks

Comment: `bathroom refitted` ... what was done?   ... what is a `pipestone`

Comment: Manufacturer and Model of the sink toilet combo? Where on Planet Earth are you located ?